# Change hero direction in place before movement on a grid based game in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, movement, grid

I've already implemented a grid based movement with all the necessary animations.

Now I would like the make the hero face the direction of the input without moving first and move only if the input direction is the same one he's facing.

E.g.: if the Hero is standing still facing up, and you press left, he will face left without moving. If you then press left again, he will move on that direction cause he's already facing it.

Here's the code:

```
void Update() {

    movementDirection.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movementDirection.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    isMoving = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, movePoint.position) > 0.1f;

    SetAnimator();

}

void FixedUpdate() {

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    if (!isMoving) {
        if (movementDirection.x != 0) { movePoint.Translate(new Vector2(movementDirection.x, 0f)); }
        else if (movementDirection.y != 0) { movePoint.Translate(new Vector2(0f, movementDirection.y)); }
    }

}

private void SetAnimator() {

    animator.SetBool("Moving", isMoving);

    if (!isMoving && movementDirection != Vector2.zero) {

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", movementDirection.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", movementDirection.y);

    }

}
```

I tried using global variables to compare Hero's direction with the input, and let the Hero move only if they're the same but due to the Update function called every frame as soon as I update the current direction with the input one the hero will start to move:

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    Directions latestGivenDirection = GetLatestGivenDirection(movementDirection);

    //this wont work, as the next frame will pass the condition and the hero will move
    if (latestGivenDirection == currentDirection) {

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, movePoint.position, movementSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if (!isMoving) {
            if (movementDirection.x != 0) { movePoint.Translate(new Vector2(movementDirection.x, 0f)); }
            else if (movementDirection.y != 0) { movePoint.Translate(new Vector2(0f, movementDirection.y)); }
        }

    }

    currentDirection = latestGivenDirection;

}
```

How can I achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: I would look into input events rather than having your input in update - this will allow you to capture and deal with individual updates better, which will set you on the right path

Comment: what do you mean by "look into input events"? Isn't it what I am doing inside the Update function? I dont know other ways to get input events

Comment: If you use `Input.GetKeyDown()` instead of `GetAxisRaw()` it will turn your player on the first press and move them on the second?

Comment: @StackDiego Unity doesn't have Input events -.- Looks like the input system revamp is coming in v2020. In that case @Jake probably has the right answer with `GetKeyDown` as `GetAxisRaw` will be polled consistently, rather than key down which will only be polled once every time the key is pressed.